# Using Gaps and Islands to Find Consecutive Hours/Dates- SQL/BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gaps-and-islands

I have a table in BigQuery that looks like this:

```
Caller_Number | month  |  day| call_time
--------------|--------|-----|----------
1             |  5     |  15 | 12:56:17
```

I want to write a SQL query for BigQuery that will allow me to count the consecutive hours in which at least one call was made (sorted by caller_number), and the consecutive days in which at least 10 consecutive hours with calls occurred (sorter by caller_number). I have been looking at the existing resources on gaps and islands, but can't seem to figure out how to apply it to consecutive dates and hours.

Comment: "sorted by caller_number" is making above question quite fuzzy. you should provide more details. you might want to share example of expected result. not having "sorted by caller_number" or having "partitioned by caller_number" would make it totally differnet clear story

Comment: Okay, the sample result would look like this:


Caller_Number  |   Month   |    Day   |  Num_Consec_Hours




The second sample result would look like this:


Caller_Number  |  Month  |  Num_Consec_Days

Answer (score 3):

Below is working example for consecutive hours
Steps are
1.“Extract” hour from call_time

```
HOUR(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE() + ' ' + call_time))
```

2.Find previous hour

```
LAG([hour]) OVER(PARTITION BY Caller_Number, [month], [day] ORDER BY [hour])
```

3.Calculate start of group of consecutive hours – 1 – start, 0 – group continuation

```
IFNULL(INTEGER([hour] - prev_hour > 1), 1)
```

4.Assign group number to each group

```
SUM(seq) OVER(PARTITION BY Caller_Number, [month], [day] ORDER BY [hour])
```

5.And finally – group by group number and count calls and hours

Hope this gives you good start for implementing similar logic for consecutive days on top of consec hours result

```
SELECT Caller_Number, [month], [day], seq_group, 
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT([hour]) AS hours_count, COUNT(1) AS calls_count 
FROM (
  SELECT Caller_Number, [month], [day], [hour],  
    SUM(seq) OVER(PARTITION BY Caller_Number, [month], [day] 
                  ORDER BY [hour]) AS seq_group
  FROM (
    SELECT Caller_Number, [month], [day], [hour], 
      IFNULL(INTEGER([hour] - prev_hour > 1), 1) AS seq
    FROM (
      SELECT Caller_Number, [month], [day], [hour], 
        LAG([hour]) OVER(PARTITION BY Caller_Number, [month], [day] 
                         ORDER BY [hour]) AS prev_hour
      FROM (
        SELECT Caller_Number, [month], [day], 
          HOUR(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE() + ' ' + call_time)) AS [hour] 
        FROM YourTable
      )
    )
  )
)
GROUP BY Caller_Number, [month], [day], seq_group
```

Comment: This worked great for me, with a slight variation: my "islands" were based on an arbitrary time gap between 2 unix timestamps, so my "seq" field was given by:       IF(
        (IF(
            prev_stamp IS NOT NULL,(stamp - prev_stamp),stamp
          ) - (3*86400)) > 0,
        1,
        0
      ) AS Seq